# akka-stream-alpakka-google-cloud-pub-sub-grpc + GRPC Http2Exception

Tags: scala, akka, google-cloud-pubsub

I have below configuration

```
alpakka.google.cloud.pubsub.grpc {
  host = "pubsub.googleapis.com"
  port = 443
  rootCa = "none"
  callCredentials = "google-application-default"
}
```

below I am trying to publish message to pubsub

```
 val system = ActorSystem()
 val settings: PubSubSettings = PubSubSettings(system)
 val publisher: GrpcPublisher = GrpcPublisher(settings, system)
val projectId = "sample_project"

val publishFlow: Flow[PublishRequest, PublishResponse, NotUsed] =
    GooglePubSub
      .publish(parallelism = 1)
      .withAttributes(PubSubAttributes.publisher(publisher))

  val pubSubReqFlow
    : Flow[ConsumerRecord[String, String], PublishRequest, NotUsed] =
    Flow[ConsumerRecord[String, String]]
      .map { record =>
        val publishMessage: PubsubMessage =
          PubsubMessage()
            .withData(ByteString.copyFromUtf8(record.value()))
        PublishRequest()
          .withTopic(s"projects/$projectId/topics/${record.topic()}")
          .addMessages(publishMessage)
      }
    Source
      .single(record)
      .via(pubSubReqFlow)
      .via(publishFlow)
      .map(_.messageIds)
      .toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.right)
      .run()
```

and I am getting below error when I run above code. Record is kafkaConsumer Record

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: http2 exception
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 1503010002
```

Comment: Probably an HTTP vs HTTPS mismatch, see https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/4063

Comment: GrpcPublisher from akka-stream-alpakka-google-cloud-pub-sub-grpc.2.0.0 is accepting only settings and actorSystem, these settings are created from above config. Is there any config we need to add ?

Comment: If you set `rootCa = "none"`, TLS will be disabled as explained in the documentation. But I'm also not sure what you should put in there instead. I filed https://github.com/akka/alpakka/issues/2321.